# Error occured during project deployement in pythonanywhere

Tags: django, bash, pythonanywhere

I have done it many times in windows operating system but now i am using Ubantu as my primery system. So when i tried makemigrations command inside my project directory(server) pythonanywhere bash throw below error.

```
(myproject) 07:29 ~/Product-Management-System (master)$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Please someone help me!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't configured your database correctly in your `settings.py`.  It's trying to connect to a MySQL database running on the computer where the Django code is running, and there is no database server there.

On PythonAnywhere, you should go to the "Databases" page and set up a MySQL server for your project there.  Then, in your `settings.py`, set up the connection settings -- `HOST` should be the one that is displayed on the "Database" page when the MySQL server has been created, as should `USER`, and the `PASSWORD` should be the one you specified when you created the server.  `PORT` should just be an empty string.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'MicroDataForMarriage',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : ' '
    }
}